# how to make excel choose between a set of values based on conditions

Tags: excel, logic, conditional-statements

I need help with excel with regards to choosing a set of value in terms of availability and priority.

For example, Part A has these 4 available parameters (TSO,TSR, TST ,TSN) however, not all parameters are available. The priority function is like TSO > TSR > TST > TSN

The method i am using now is very inefficient as i create a lot of extra columns and comparing with =if. In essence, its ugly,time wasting and not 100% foolproof.

Therefore, i am trying to see if there are any sets of excel function to effectively do this. The first priority value to use is TSO (if value is displayed) but if it is not available (blank) i would move to see TSR. If it is blank i would move to see TST, so on and so forth until the last choice TSN.

I have attached a picture to give you guys a clearer picture

[Example of how it looks like for a clearer visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyzRf.png)

Comment: You need to include some sample data and expected outcomes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the VLOOKUP() function where you can pull any value of your preference using a unique id. So you can use TSO, TSR, TST,and TSN as your IDs.

EXAMPLE

=IF(OR(AND(Sheet2!B1<>"",A1="TSO"),AND(Sheet2!B1<>"",A1="TSR"),AND(Sheet2!B1<>"",A1="TST"),AND(Sheet2!B1<>"",A1="TSN")),VLOOKUP(A1,DATA1,1,FALSE),"")

You may share a screen shot of your sample excel template so that i work on immediately

Comment: Yep i have added it. please take a look to have a clearer picture

Comment: I can't see a photo attached!

Comment: aww man, this website makes it so damn hard for people to post pictures. it's okay. thank you for the time taken to look at my question